# Communication between the Document Class and MovieClip Class: error 1009

Tags: actionscript-3

I am learning how to make MovieClip classes. All I am trying to do is give the MovieClip the ability to move with the left and right arrow keys, but it's not working.

Here is my code for my Document Class Main:

```
package  {   

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip{

         var blueBall:Ball = new Ball; //This is line 7

          public function Main()
        {
            addChild(blueBall)
        }

    }

 }
```

My code for my Ball class is:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Ball extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Ball()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed); //This is Line 11
        }

         function keyPressed(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
             switch (evt.keyCode)
        {
            case Keyboard.RIGHT :
                this.x +=  10;
                break;
            case Keyboard.LEFT :
                this.x -=  10;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

}

When I run this in the debug, I get this error:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Ball()[C:\Users\Joel\Desktop\Flash\Projects\DropClassTest\Ball.as:11]
    at Main()[C:\Users\Joel\Desktop\Flash\Projects\DropClassTest\Main.as:7]

Now, if I just leave my Main document class blank, and just drag and drop the blueBall Movieclip out of the Library, it works the way I want it to, but once I try to use the document class to do it, it's not working.

Needless to say, I am quite lost, even thought the debugger is telling me what lines are wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access the stage from inside the Ball class before the ball is added to the stage. Before an object is added to the stage, it does not have direct access to the stage.

**Option 1:** You could pass the stage from the main class to the Ball constructor.

Add this to your Ball class' imports:

```
import flash.display.Stage;
```

Add a stage parameter to the Ball class' constructor:

```
public function Ball(stage:Stage):void {
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
}
```

And pass the stage to your Ball instance (in Main)

```
var blueBall:Ball = new Ball(stage);
```

**Option 2:** You can listen for the ADDED_TO_STAGE event inside of the Ball class and add the KEY_DOWN listener once ADDED_TO_STAGE occurs:

Inside the Ball class import the Event class:

```
import flash.events.Event;
```

Replace your constructor with this:

```
public function Ball():void {
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
}
```

Then add your KEY_DOWN listener inside the ADDED_TO_STAGE listener:

```
function addedToStage(evt:Event):void {
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
}
```